# Get the current site url

Tags: development

How to get the current site url in SharePoint?

I am using `SPContext.Current.Site.Url` but this returns parent site url.

If I create a new site in existing site and activate my feature in it, and call it, it doesn't returns me current site url, it returns me the parent site url.

Any idea?

Comment: SharePoint has confusing mismatch between object names and what people call sites: SPSite is "site collection", SPWeb is "site". So you call actually returns Url to site collection that is one of the ancestors of your site (not necessary immediate one).

Comment: Object "Site/SPSite" refers to Site Collection. Object "Web/SPWeb" refers to the site. This is just because of poor naming conventions from the sharepoint team. Try SPContext.Current.Web.Url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be `SPContext.Current.Web.Url`

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
string urlpath = "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + "/Sites/" + siteCollectionName;
```